# Custom function comparison returns incorrect value, but only when the lower value is between 3 and 9

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I am writing a custom function for google sheets to give me the win/loss values of volleyball matches. To do that I get the range of the games and just say if the current range value for game 1 is greater than the other range value for game 1, increase to the wins column. But for some reason, when the score for the losing team is between 3 and 9 (inclusive) it will say that they have the higher score (compared to 25).

```
function GETNUMWINS(currentRange, otherRange) {
  var wins = 0;
  var numGames = currentRange.length;

  for(let i = 0; i < numGames; i++){
    if(currentRange[i] > otherRange[i]){
      wins++;
    }
  }
  return wins;
}
```

For example, a match of

| Team A | Team B |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 9 |
| 25 | 15 |

will result in that function returning 1 win for each team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then it's probably considering the numbers as strings, subsequently considering "in alphabetical order" 3 greater than 25

Try:

```
(currentRange[i]*1 > otherRange[i]*1)
```